# How to use agetty from the command line

Tags: tty, getty

Is it possible to use `agetty` from the command line? I tried the command

```
sudo agetty -s 34800 tty8 linux
```

but it returns after a few seconds and `tty8` is not open. Is it the expected behaviour?

Also, trying to start it in the background with

```
sudo agetty -s 34800 tty8 linux &> /dev/null &
```

returns immediately. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your line, I get the following in /var/log/secure (fedora19):

```
getty[12336]: bad speed: 34800
```

try this:

```
agetty -s 38400 -t 600 tty8 linux
```

Comment: Thank you, adding this timeout allows me to get a tty. But I am confused. Why did a timeout fix my problem?

Comment: There is also the problem of starting this command in the background with `&` (added to the question) which still fails?

Comment: No,you specified the wrong speed. The timeout can be left out of course. Use the right speed (38400) and the bachgrounding should work. Note that the "&" means that the job will be put into background and the shell returns immediately.

Comment: Yes, with the right speed, it works. The backgrounding however does not. The job is stopped immediately.